# Can't get all author using WP_User_Query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to show all authors as well as the pagination of the result. So using bellow code it's not returning any users.

```
// Pagination vars
$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ? (int) get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$users_per_page = 12; // RAISE THIS AFTER TESTING ;)

$args = array(
    'number' => $users_per_page,
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'role' => 'Author',
);

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$total_users = $users->get_total(); // How many users we have in total (beyond the current page)
$num_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page); // How many pages of users we will need

if ( $users->get_results() ) {

    foreach( $users->get_results() as $user )  {
        // $firstname = $user->first_name;
        // $lastname = $user->last_name;
        // $email = $user->user_email;
        $author_thumb_url = get_avatar_url( $user->ID );
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
            echo '<div class="author-wrapper">';
                echo '<div class="author-thumb">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$author_thumb_url.'">';                                            
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="author-description">';
                    echo '<h2>'. $user->first_name . ' ' .  $user->last_name . '</h2>';
                    echo '<p>'. get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->ID ) . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';    
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }  
} 
?>
```

In `args` I have also used **'role' => 'author'** and **'role__in' => 'author'** but no result is showing.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop might be incorrect.  This is working for me.  I also wrapper your columns in a row and container.

Try

```
// Pagination vars
$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ? (int) get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$users_per_page = 12; // RAISE THIS AFTER TESTING ;)

$args = array(
    'number' => $users_per_page,
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'role' => 'author',
);

$users = new WP_User_Query( $args );

$total_users = $users->get_total(); // How many users we have in total (beyond the current page)
$num_pages = ceil($total_users / $users_per_page); // How many pages of users we will need

if ( $users->results ) {
    echo '<div class="container"><div class="row">';
    foreach( $users->results as $user )  {
        // $firstname = $user->first_name;
        // $lastname = $user->last_name;
        // $email = $user->user_email;
        $author_thumb_url = get_avatar_url( $user->ID );
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
            echo '<div class="author-wrapper">';
                echo '<div class="author-thumb">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$author_thumb_url.'">';                                            
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="author-description">';
                    echo '<h2>'. $user->first_name . ' ' .  $user->last_name . '</h2>';
                    echo '<p>'. get_the_author_meta( 'description', $user->ID ) . '</p>';
                echo '</div>';    
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }  
    echo '</div></div>';
} 
``
```